# Has Quine's set theory NF been proved consistent (relative to ZF)

Tags: set-theory

This question is an updated repetition of mathoverflow.net question [The status of 'the consistency of NF relative to ZF'](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132103) which I asked about a year ago. At that time the answer was that "the jury is still out". What was being reviewed was an alledged proof of the consistency of NF (relative to ZF) that had been presented at Cambridge by Randall Holmes during April or May of 2013. Since then I have heard nothing more about this. Is any further information available regarding that proof?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add a link.

Comment: A side note: the claim at the time was stronger than "NF is consistent relative to ZF;" Holmes' statement was that NF is consistent relative to the theory of simple types + infinity, or equivalently bounded Zermelo set theory (see http://www.logicmatters.net/2012/11/the-consistency-of-nf/).

Comment: The proof is available at the [author's webpage](http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/): see [here](http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/holmes/nfdoc.pdf).

Comment: Garabed, it's much better to bump your old question with an edit or even a bounty than to post a duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks for all this information. I wonder when this achievement will be announced to the general mathematical public.